# Get id from entity

Tags: symfony

I am a beginner in symfony 2.8, I use pugxmultiuserBundle.

My users are:

- admin
- Entreprise
- Etudiant
- Encadreur
- Enseignant

For the registration of the Enseignan, the Etudiant and the Entreprise everything works perfectl.

But my problem at the level of the Encadreur, I want the Entreprise to manage the account creation of its Encadreur, creating its march but I do not know how to recover the id of the current company in the table of framers

[controller of register encadreur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZxiv.png)
[Builderform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QMdf.png)

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationEmployeFormType;
use UserBundle\Entity\Encadreur;
use UserBundle\Entity\Entreprise;


class RegistrationEmployeController extends Controller {
   public function registerEmployeAction() {   
     return $this->container
                 ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
                 ->register('UserBundle\Entity\Encadreur');

     // $this->setEntreprise($this->getId()) 
  }
}
```

builderform:

```
<?php



namespace UserBundle\Form\Type;

use FOS\UserBundle\Util\LegacyFormHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
//use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
use UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationEmployeFormType as BaseType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class RegistrationEmployeFormType extends AbstractType {
  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $class;

  /**
   * @param string $class The User class name
   */
  public function __construct($class) {
      $this->class = $class;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
      $builder
        ->add('email',      LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType'  ), array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('plainPassword', LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType'), array(
            'type' => LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType'),
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
        ->add('entreprise')
        ->add('firstName','text', array('required' => false))
        ->add('lastName','text', array('required' => false));
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => $this->class,
        'csrf_token_id' => 'registration',
        // BC for SF < 2.8
        'intention' => 'registration',
    ));
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getName() {
      return $this->getBlockPrefix();
  }

  public function getParent() {
    return 'fos_user_registration';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return 'Employe_registration';
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If the person who is registering the employee works at the Enterprise or has a reference to it, you can grab it from their entity.

In your controller:

```
public function registerEmployeAction()
{   
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $entreprise = $user->getEntreprise();
    $encadreuer = $this
                    ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
                    ->register('UserBundle\Entity\Encadrer')
                  ;
    $encadreuer->setEntreprise($entreprise);

    return $encadreur;
 }
```

Comment: error : Attempted to call an undefined method named "setEntreprise" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response".

Comment: Did you attempt to do this through the form? Because the form has mistakes in it as well.

Comment: the probleme is that $encadreur in this situation appears as a Response

Comment: Right. Which is what your form is using to post. Did you run this through the form?

Also, is the rest of your controller setup in the correct way? Does it have routes and request / response attributes or are you just activating this method through some other means?

Comment: Post your actual controller code as well as entities then because what you've posted here is not configured correctly.

Comment: Which controller should i post?

Comment: This controller.